# Referencing external global variables fails miserably

Tags: c, gcc, linker, binary, ld

I'm trying to embed binary file `B` into executable `A` at linking time, on Linux (64bit).

***`B` is a simple text file...***

`Hi, I'm a text file in plain ASCII.`

...which is turned into a relocatable object with `ld -r -bbinary -oB.o B`. Its `symtab` reports three global variables, the names of which are pretty self-explanatory:

1. `_binary_B_start`
2. `_binary_B_end`
3. `_binary_B_size`

***This is `A.c`...***

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern const size_t _binary_B_size;

int main(int argc, char * * argv)
{
    printf("size: %zu\n", _binary_B_size);
    return 0;
}
```

...which is compiled and linked with `B.o`: `gcc -oA A.c B.o`.
Unfortunately, as soon as executable `A` tries to access `_binary_B_size`, it gets abruptly terminated with a `SIGSEGV`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are misunderstanding the semantics of `_binary_B_size`. It is not a `size_t` lvalue, as you seem to believe. It is a zero size *absolutely positioned section* (a label), whose address equals the size of your binary blob data. Try `objdump -t` on your file an you will see `*ABS*` in the corresponding column.

So the proper usage would be

```
extern unsigned char _binary_B_size[];

int main()
{
    printf("size: %zu\n", (size_t) _binary_B_size);
}
```

You can also use `end - start` method and get the same result

```
extern unsigned char _binary_B_start[];
extern unsigned char _binary_B_end[];

int main()
{
    printf("size: %zu\n", (size_t) (_binary_B_end - _binary_B_start));
}
```

Basically, the main consideration here is that there's no reason for `_binary_B_size` to be a `size_t` lvalue. It is effectively a constant with value pre-determined at compile time. There's no reason for it to occupy storage. And what you see above is one way to encode such constant values in object files.